# avoid needing to declare 'var me = this' for javascript prototype functions

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, javascript-objects

Currently, I create objects in javascript by declaring a construction (regular function) then add methods to the prototype like so

```
function Test(){
}
Test.prototype.test1 = function(){
    var me = this;
}
```

However, I would like to avoid having to declare `var me = this` at the top of every function. The following seems to work, but seems like it would be very inefficient:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = 0;
(function(){

     function createTest(){
        var me;
        function Test(){
            this.n = n;
            this.testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            n++;
        }

        Test.prototype.test1 = function(){
            me.test2();
        };
        Test.prototype.test2 = function(){
            alert(me.n);
            $.getJSON('test.php', {}, function(reply)
                //want to be able to use 'me' here
                me.newField = reply;
            });
        };

        var t = new Test();
        me = t;
        return t;
    }
    window['createTest'] = createTest;
})();

var t = createTest();
t.test1();
var t2 = createTest();
t2.test1();
t.test1();
});
```

This code outputs the expected, but is it actually as inefficient as it looks (the Test object being re-declared every time you call createTest())?

Anyhoo, this would seem a bit hacky... is there a completely different way to do this that is better?

EDIT: The real reason I would like to do this is so that callbacks like the one in test2 will have references to the correct `this`.

Comment: You should read this (excuse the pun): http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Comment: very informative. Thanks a lot! Oh, and your pun is excused :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is bind the current `this` value to a `function` and store a copy somewhere. *(For the sake of efficiency.)*

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    // Most modern browsers will have this built-in but just in case.
    Function.prototype.bind = function (obj) {
        var slice = [].slice,
            args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
            self = this,
            nop = function () { },
            bound = function () {
                return self.apply(this instanceof nop ? this : (obj || {}),
                                    args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        nop.prototype = self.prototype;
        bound.prototype = new nop();
        return bound;
    };
}

function Test(n) {
    this.n = n;
    this.callback = (function () {
        alert(this.n);
    }).bind(this)
}

Test.prototype.test1 = function () {
    this.test2();
}

Test.prototype.test2 = function () {
    doSomething(this.callback);
}

function doSomething(callback) {
    callback();
}

var t = new Test(2);
t.test1();
```

Comment: yeah but then if you had a callback inside of any of the prototypes, `this` will not refer to the object. sorry for not being clear enough. please see the edit.

Comment: Hmmm, so would this mean that for each function in the Test object, I would have to add `this.func = (function(){...}).bind(this)` in the constructor? If this is the case, I think that just declaring `var me = this` at the top of each `Test.prototype` func would be cleaner...

Comment: @Hersheezy - You don't necessarily need to do that. If it were up to me though I would keep the `this` reference local to the function that needs it. That way you can avoid that factory style object creation.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what you are getting at. I can see avoiding callback execution inside of a prototype function as a useful pattern. As far as 'avoiding the factory style object creation' you mention, I will have to think about this a bit more... not particularly familiar with this pattern...

Answer (score 2):

I realize your question was not tagged with jQuery, but you are using it in your example, so my solution also utilizes jQuery.

I sometimes use the [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to avoid callback context. [Look at this simple jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YVsK9/1/). Source below.

```
function Test(){
    this.bind();
}

Test.prototype.bind = function(){
    $('input').bind('change', $.proxy(this.change, this)); 
    // you could use $.proxy on anonymous functions also (as in your $.getJSON example)
}
Test.prototype.change = function(event){ 
    // currentField must be set from e.target
    // because this is `Test` instance
    console.log(this instanceof Test);          // true
    console.log(event.target == $('input')[0]); // true
    this.currentField = event.target;           // set new field
};

function createTest(){
    return new Test();
}

$(function(){ // ready callback calls test factory
    var t1 = createTest();
});
```

Comment: Very cool! Good point, I should have tagged with jQuery... I think I will play around with this and see how much this will suit my needs in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I just declare a local variable that references this, wherever I need a reference to this in a callback:

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  var that=this;
  setTimeout(function() {
     that.something="This goes to the right object";
  }, 5000);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use bind() like this:

```
Function Foo() {
   this.bar = this.bar.bind(this);
   // ... repeated for each function ...
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
}
```

What this gives you is that every time you create a new Foo instance, the methods are bound to the current instance, so you can use them as callback functions for setTimeout() et al.